# How to properly separate from Shiva Linga?

Tags: shiva

I have not been a good devotee to the Shiv Ling and feel that I can't take care of it the way it deserves, what should I do to separate from it?

Comment: Pleasing Lord Shiva is not that difficult .. if you simply bath the Lingam daily that will be good taking care of it. But if you really want to get rid of it then you can either donate it to some temple or immerse it in water preferably in a river.

Comment: @Rickross, thank you, I do not have a Guru, and have read online that I should have a fountain of water on it flowing day and night and if I cannot I will be punished. That is why I thought of seperating from it

Comment: No ..many people have Shivalingas in their homes but they don't have those fountains constantly dropping water on the Lingams. I also have Shivalingas but do not have fountains. If you can bath once in the morning that will be fine. Lighting lamp and incense sticks is also very beneficial. But still if you don't want to keep it you can submerge it in a lake or river.

Comment: Thank you so much, that is so refreshing. Should I chant the Shiva Mantra while I do this or should I be in silence as I offer him water

Comment: Yes you can chant any Shiva mantras you like or you can do it without chanting too.